# Ocaml: why these types?

Tags: types, ocaml

Hi could someone please explain why the types are as outlined below?  I understand that they would have to be int because `x+y+z` but the number of arguments (ie `->`) seems arbitrary to me.

```
let f x y z = x+y+z in f 1 2 3      // int
let f x y z = x+y+z in f 1 2        // int -> int
let f x y z = x+y+z in f            // int -> int -> int -> int
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand slightly on valtron's answer. It is all straightforward once you understand the type of `f`. As valtron says, its type is `int -> int -> int -> int`. Fundamentally, this is the type of a function that takes an `int` and returns a function of type `int -> int -> int`. So if you were to pass just `1` to `f` (which you don't do in your example), you'd get back something of type `int -> int -> int`.

In a similar way, if you pass an `int` to this returned function, you get back a function of type `int -> int`. This is something you do in your example: `f 1 2` does exactly this: it passes `1` to `f`, then passes `2` to the function that `f` returns. This second function call
returns something of type `int -> int`, as the toplevel shows you.

In the same way, specifying three values after `f` returns a value of type `int`. This is what's happening in your first example.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `f`, as you defined it, is `int -> int -> int -> int`. Each argument you provide `f` shaves an `int` off the type of the expression because of currying. For example, `f 1 2` is `int -> int`, a function that takes an int and returns an int, because `x` and `y` are curried with `1` and `2`, so they're not parameters anymore.